# Java code for building epub is not working

Tags: java, zip, epub

I made a java class to read a txt file and convert into EPUB format, My code is able to generated necessary files into ZipOutputStream (java.util.zip) object.
Generated zio file contains following files:

1. index.html
2. mimetype
3. content.opf
4. toc.ncx
5. META-INF/container.xml

But when I tried to load epub file is it unworkable. Online epub validation (http://threepress.org/document/epub-validate/) throws error that "META-INF/container.xml" file was not found, however strange thing about this is I can extract zip archive properly and everything is in place also if I recreate extract to a zip file using windows winzip utility that epub is working!
Here is the piece of code used to create container.xml file

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator;

public class ToEPub {

private String rootDir;

private static String metaFolder = "META-INF";
private static String oebpsFolder = "";// "OEBPS";
private static String containerFile = "container.xml";
private static String contentPpfFile = "content.opf";
private static String tocFile = "toc.ncx";
private static String baseFileName;
private static String baseFilePathHTML;
private static String baseFileNameHTML;
private String baseFilePath;
private ZipOutputStream zip;
private String baseFileZipPath;

public ToEPub(String fileName) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    rootDir = file.getParent();
    baseFileName = file.getName();
    baseFilePath = file.getPath();
    baseFilePathHTML = baseFilePath + ".html";
    baseFileNameHTML = baseFileName.substring(0, baseFileName
            .lastIndexOf("."))
            + ".html";
    baseFileZipPath = baseFilePath.substring(0, baseFilePath
            .lastIndexOf("."))
            + ".epub";
    zip = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(baseFileZipPath));

}

public void start() throws IOException {

    createMimeFile();
    createMeta();
    readConnent();
    createContentList();
    createTocFile();

    //zip.flush();
    zip.close();
    /*
     * Reading Creating Zip again
     */
    ZipFile zfile = new ZipFile(new File(baseFileZipPath));
    System.out.println(zfile.size() + " Files");
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> itr = zfile.entries();
    while(itr.hasMoreElements()){
        ZipEntry entry = itr.nextElement();
        System.out.println(entry.getName()+" Size: "+entry.getCompressedSize()+"/"+entry.getSize() +" CRC: "+ entry.getCrc());

    }
}

public void createMimeFile() throws IOException {
    byte[] content = "application/epub+zip".getBytes("UTF-8");
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("mimetype");
    entry.setMethod(ZipEntry.STORED);
    entry.setSize(20);
    entry.setCompressedSize(20);
    entry.setCrc(0x2CAB616F); // pre-computed
    zip.putNextEntry(entry);

    zip.write(content);
    zip.closeEntry();

}

public void readConnent() throws IOException {
    String thisLine;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(baseFilePath);
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String outFile = oebpsFolder + File.separator + baseFileNameHTML;
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(baseFileNameHTML);
    zip.putNextEntry(entry);
    zip.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    zip.write("<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n"
            .getBytes("UTF-8"));
    while ((thisLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) { // while loop
        // begins here
        zip.write(("<p>" + thisLine + "</p>\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } // end while
    zip.write("</html>".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    zip.closeEntry();
}

public void createContentList() throws IOException{
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(contentPpfFile);
    zip.putNextEntry(entry);
     zip.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
     zip.write("<package xmlns=\"http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf\" version=\"2.0\" unique-identifier=\"uuid_id\">".getBytes("UTF-8"));
     zip.write("<metadata xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:opf=\"http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf\" xmlns:dcterms=\"http://purl.org/dc/terms/\" xmlns:calibre=\"http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net/2009/metadata\" xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\">\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); 
     zip.write("<dc:language>en</dc:language>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
     zip.write("<dc:creator opf:role=\"aut\">Open Mobile Alliance</dc:creator>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));

     zip.write("<meta name=\"calibre:timestamp\" content=\"2011-11-11T15:02:14.075083+00:00\"/>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); 
     zip.write("<dc:title>OMA Specification</dc:title>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
     zip.write("<dc:contributor opf:role=\"bkp\">calibre (0.8.22) [http://calibre-ebook.com]</dc:contributor>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
     zip.write("<dc:identifier id=\"uuid_id\" opf:scheme=\"uuid\">22fb9171-78bd-4bd1-89f8-7cae3a497c7c</dc:identifier>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); 
     zip.write("<dc:subject>Template</dc:subject>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
     zip.write("</metadata>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); 
     zip.write("<manifest>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
     zip.write(("<item href=\""+baseFileNameHTML+"\" id=\"id1\" media-type=\"application/xhtml+xml\"/>\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
     zip.write("<item href=\"toc.ncx\" media-type=\"application/x-dtbncx+xml\" id=\"ncx\"/>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); 
     zip.write("</manifest>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); 
     zip.write("<spine toc=\"ncx\">\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
     zip.write("<itemref idref=\"id1\"/>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); 
     zip.write("</spine>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
     zip.write("<guide/>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); 
     zip.write("</package>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); 
     zip.closeEntry();
}
public void createTocFile() throws IOException{
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(tocFile);
    zip.putNextEntry(entry);
    zip.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    zip.write("<container version=\"1.0\" xmlns=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container\">\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); 
    zip.write("<rootfiles>".getBytes("UTF-8"));

    zip.write(("<rootfile full-path=\""+contentPpfFile
              +"\" media-type=\"application/oebps-package+xml\"/>\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));

    zip.write("</rootfiles>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); 
    zip.write("</container>".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    zip.closeEntry();
}
public void createMeta() throws IOException{

    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(metaFolder+File.separator+containerFile);

    zip.putNextEntry(entry);
    zip.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    zip.write("<container version=\"1.0\" xmlns=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container\">\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    zip.write("<rootfiles>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    zip.write("<rootfile full-path=\"content.opf\" media-type=\"application/oebps-package+xml\"/>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    zip.write("</rootfiles>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    zip.write("</container>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    zip.closeEntry();
}
public void createMetaInfo() throws IOException{
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(metaFolder+File.separator);
    zip.putNextEntry(entry);
    zip.closeEntry();
}

}
```

I tried change UTF-8 to default but not avail

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I change

```
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(metaFolder+File.separator+containerFile);
```

to

```
final ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(metaFolder + "/" + containerFile);
```

it works for me (on Windows). EpubCheck still shows some (new) errors, you should check them too.

---

Make sure that you put the entries into the `zip`/`epub` in the following order:

- `mimetype`
- `META-INF/*`
- everything else

---

I can find some differences between your original epub and a repacked version:

```
# unzip -l android.epub
Archive:  android.epub
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       20  11-17-2011 14:48   mimetype
      227  11-17-2011 14:48   META-INF\container.xml
     1589  11-17-2011 14:48   android.html
     1076  11-17-2011 14:48   content.opf
      223  11-17-2011 14:48   toc.ncx
---------                     -------
     3135                     5 files

# unzip -l my.epub
Archive:  my.epub
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       20  11-17-2011 14:48   mimetype
        0  11-17-2011 11:05   META-INF/
      227  11-17-2011 14:48   META-INF/container.xml
     1076  11-17-2011 14:48   content.opf
      223  11-17-2011 14:48   toc.ncx
     1589  11-17-2011 14:48   android.html
---------                     -------
     3135                     6 files
```

I'd try putting a `META-INF` folder entry to the zip file.

[EpubCheck](http://code.google.com/p/epubcheck/) also reports the error:

```
ERROR: android.epub: Required META-INF/container.xml resource is missing
```

If the `META-INF` entry isn't help check the source of EpubCheck maybe it can help.

Comment: Additionally, ensure that you don't compress the mimetype file.

Comment: thanks you very much for reply, I changed the order of file/folder creations but result remained same. Also i made mimetype file according to epub standard and validation dont have any issue with that

Comment: Could you upload your epub somewhere?

Comment: @palacsin thanks for bringing culprit, adding folder to zip is another tedious task. Normally when you append slash to entry  filename it will be treated as directory but an empty directory entry doesnt seem possible to create it will put one file (without any name) inside that before we can populate it. I tried this and its not working with this

Comment: Many years later, this post helped me diagnose a similar issue, thanks @palacsint. In my case, I was generating an epub on Windows, and got the same error. In my case, my Node-based script was writing Windows-style backslashes into file paths in the archive. When I changed that to forward slashes, the EPUBCheck error disappeared. Perhaps EPUBCheck needs the posix-style forward slashes in the zip file's central directory when checking for container.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a long time ago but just in case anyone comes across this problem again, I think the problem may be in the source code of the `createMeta()` method.

```
    zip.write("<rootfile full-path=\"content.opf\" media-type=\"application/oebps-package+xml\"/>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

shouldn't it be as follows?

```
    zip.write("<rootfile full-path=\"OEBPS/content.opf\" media-type=\"application/oebps-package+xml\"/>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
```